# How to add "sign up with your Facebook account feature" in a website built in Java EE?

Tags: java-ee-7, jakarta-ee

In my website which is built in Java EE, I want to add a feature so that the users can login into my webpage using their Facebook login details or Gmail login details.

Comment: and what have you tried? What research have you done? Show some effort, don't just dump your work on others.

Answer (score 0):

You can go through Facebook APIs for JAVA developers and can use them in your application like, google calendar API, google-Picasa-web API etc. First you can access only publicly shared objects without credentials. If you want private objects access, you can implement these API calls by using OAuth. Please read below resources for your reference as per your project needs:

http://projects.spring.io/spring-social-facebook/

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apis-and-sdks